# What is the piano song from Ep 18 13:12 of parasyte?

Tags: music, parasyte

Does anyone know the title of that piano song. I have searched a lot and still have not found it.

Comment: Have you tried using any music recognition apps for smartphones? Maybe uploading a piece of audio to online music recognition sites for computers?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty simple piano melody. Maybe not good enough to be worth including in the ost. Try browsing unofficial soundtrack torrents, maybe it's there somewhere.

Comment: Is there a link to hear this melody (or portion of the episode) online? Youtube? I sadly do not have the full episode available to me.

Answer (score 2):

It is the piano version of "I Am", this melody is  included in the album *寄生獣 セイの格率 特典オリジナルサウンドトラック*

you can listen to it here  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXDbj4L2Y2U&list=RDmXDbj4L2Y2U